# How can i download a msys package with all dependencies on it using a simple pacman command?

Tags: download, package, msys

The question is simple.

I want to download a package (`mingw-w64-x86_64-libshout`) with all the dependencies on it recursively (dependencies  of dependencies of ...).

I don't want to install the package in msys2 posix platform. Just to download it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [quasi-msys2](https://github.com/HolyBlackCat/quasi-msys2) (which I'm the author of), you can do it from an existing MSYS2 installation or from WSL:

```
git clone https://github.com/holyblackcat/quasi-msys2
cd quasi-msys2
echo MINGW64 >msystem.txt
make get-deps mingw-w64-x86_64-libshout | xargs make cache-download
```

Where `mingw-w64-x86_64-libshout` is the package name.

The packages are downloaded to `./cache`.

Caveat: it only supports packages prefixed with `mingw-??-`, not the ones from the `MSYS` environment. By default the `UCRT64` environment is used, but it can be changed by creating/modifying `msystem.txt` after cloning the repo.

It doesn't use `pacman`, and will work on other operating systems without MSYS2 installed.

Comment: Great idea, use a tool that you need to compile with CMAKE in order to get the CMAKE in the first place! (I'm trying to get it from https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-cmake, but packman returns 404 when trying to install and .zst can't be opened with anything I have)

Comment: @GrayFace The original question implies that OP already has MSYS2 installed, the other answer assumes that too. *"packman returns 404"* If this is an old MSYS2 installation, you should try reinstalling. Otherwise you should point it to a different mirror. *".zst can't be opened with anything I have"* It's a zstd archive. Quick googling points to this: https://github.com/mcmilk/7-Zip-zstd Or use `tar -xf` (which needs `zstd.exe` to be installed).

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`pacman -Sw yourPackage`

they will be downloaded to /var/cache/pacman/pkg

use `--cachedir` if you want to download the package to another folder

and to install them from that folder use:
`pacman -U dir/yourPackage1 dir/yourPackage2`